# Typescript - conditional types based on value in a for of list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

So these are my types:

```
export type typeOne = {
  A: string;
  B: string;
};

export type typeTwo = {
  A: string;
  C: string;
};

export type Result = typeOne | typeTwo; //condition
```

And this is the use case:

```
for (const item: Result of list) {
   const something = item.B ? 'B exsist' : item.C;
   return something;
}
```

It keeps returning error:

> TS2339: Property 'B' does not exist on type 'Result'.  Property 'B' does not exist on type 'typeTwo'.

and also for the other one:

> TS2339: Property 'C' does not exist on type 'Result'.  Property 'C' does not exist on type 'typeOne'.

Do you have any idea how can I fix this?

**Note**: The following error is also happening for the loop:

> TS2483: The left-hand side of a 'for...of' statement cannot use a type annotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the nuances of TypeScript is that if you have a union type of objects, you can only access the fields that are common between them. It is common to use this technique to add a common field that can tell the two apart. For instance:

```
export type typeOne = {
  type: 'one';
  A: string;
  B: string;
};

export type typeTwo = {
  type: 'two'
  A: string;
  C: string;
};

export type Result = typeOne | typeTwo; //condition 

for (const item: Result of list) {
   const something = item.type === 'one' ? 'B exists' : item.C;
   return something;
}
```

In this case, `type` acts as a discriminator. Read more here: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions

---

Alternatively, you can create a custom [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) to differentiate between the two types. This involves a function that takes your union type and evaluates at runtime if the value is of a particular type. You can use a type assertion to access a non-shared field in the union:

```
function isTypeOne(result: Result): result is typeOne {
  return (result as typeOne).B !== undefined;
}

for (const item: Result of list) {
   const something = isTypeOne(item) ? 'B exists' : item.C;
   return something;
}
```

Here, if `isTypeOne` fails, `typeOne` can be safely eliminated from `Result`, thus the type is inferred as `typeTwo`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [an `in` type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator) to discriminate a union of object types with unequal keys:

```
for (const item: Result of list) {
   const something = "B" in item ? 'B exsist' : item.C;
   return something;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYDnAPIDtUF44DeAUHHAIIBccAzjFAJZYDmA3CXAEJW0PNsC+bIqEiw0KccAAqAdwhx8xUpRp1GrdgGFuavkUFFh4aPCQSASsGoBXADbx8ZzDjgAfSbIgs4Aeh8BjCCwAE3oYeiC4Q2Dgf1sAQyhUQKxaOFt6WipLG3sAbQBdNgAzaDgAChS0sOAAWzgIYvTMmABKQnY4KvhqCFrgGAALdQU4ACIOMbhGaZg6uAB+OAByDjhQahbluCoa2oA6TQEgA)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the last error you mentioned:

> "TS2483: The left-hand side of a 'for...of' statement cannot use a type annotation."

The `Result` type definition should be part of your declaration of `list`. That way, there is no need to specify that the left-hand side of the statement is a `Result`.

For example, assuming `list` is an array:

```
const list: Array<Result> = [{A: 'foo', B: 'bar'}, {A: 'foo', C: 'baz'}]
for (const item of list) {
  // Run code from other answers here
}
```